# RabbitMQ message rates for the past hour

Tags: rabbitmq

How can I get information about message rates for the past hour?

Like this Management Plugin:

[image]

I tried:

```
http://server:XXXXX/api/overview?msg_rates_age=3600&msg_rates_incr=60
```

[image]

I don't understand what those "samples" numbers mean? How to get correct 100...120 like "rate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sample` statistic is defined as:

> Snapshots showing how **the value** has changed over the requested time period.

Here, *the value* is the item you are measuring to get your rate.

So, for example, in your case, there are 474673496 messages in the "publish" category - and that total number has been changing over time, as given by each of the `sample` and `timestamp` pair of values. The sample number (messages total) decreases as you go further back in time, with each previous timestamp.

(The timestamps are given as milliseconds since [the Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). So `1658595600000` is `Saturday, July 23, 2022 5:00:00 PM GMT`.)

You can use this data to see how the rate has changed over sampling periods.

---

Some documentation for this can be found here:

[RabbitMQ Management HTTP Stats](https://raw.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_9/priv/www/doc/stats.html)

This documentation is for an older version of Rabbit (v3.6.9) - so there may be an updated documentation page (if so I was not able to find it).

---

**Update**

The most recent documentation:

http://raw.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/v3.10.6/deps/rabbitmq_management/priv/www/api/index.html

It is now a single consolidated page, instead of 2 separate pages.

Comment: Thx! This was the misunderstanding: too large numbers. 120 requests * 60 seconds = 7200 - this is approximately requests per minute.

Comment: OK, yes - these numbers are not intuitive (to me, anyway). If you wanted (just as an example) to get the rate per hour over the last 5 hours, I think you would have to use `msg_rates_age=18000&msg_rates_incr=3600` - and then parse the JSON response to subtract each previous "sample" value from the one above it.

Comment: Yeap! Thx! That's all I needed